# jquery show/hide when class changes

Tags: jquery, hide, show-hide, show

I have two buttons, but I only want the second one to show if the first one has a certain class (which will change when the user clicks on it).

This is what I've tried. I don't get any errors, but the show/hide doesn't work. The second button is supposed to show when the first one has the class `btn-success` and must be hidden otherwise.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if($(".save_ans").length && (".btn-success").length){
    $(".submit_ans").show();
  }else{
   $(".submit_ans").hide();
  }
   });
```

jsfiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/btc6rg9d/

Comment: You need to hook to the `click` event of the first button and display the second at that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `hasClass` to check if `save_ans` has `btn-success` class depending on this hide/show your next element.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(".save_ans").hasClass('btn-success') ? $(".submit_ans").show() :
  $(".submit_ans").hide()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<a class='btn save_ans btn-warning' href="#">Save answer</a> <br> <br>

<a class='btn  submit_ans' href="#">Submit Answers</a> <br>
```

Comment: Thanks @Swati, the code snippet works as expected, but for some reason it's not working in my project. Basically the user chooses an answer, then clicks on "Save Answer", and then an ajax call changes the class and saves the answer (without refreshing). With your code, the "Submit Answers" button never becomes visible. Any idea what might be preventing the code from working as expected?

Comment: can you show your updated code with ajax ?

Comment: Ah, never mind, I found the error! Thanks again :)

Comment: I added the new code to the wrong place :/